# How to use a loop in perl

Tags: perl, loops

I have a sub modul in perl to compare files regarding their time.
Now I will not only compare "lin" in directory A and "LINT" in directory B. How can I add more files in A and B?

```
...    
sub find_newer_files {
        my ( $dirA, $extA, $dirB, $extB ) = @_;
    .....
    find_newer_files(
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin",  # directory_A => extension_A
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT", # directory B
    );
...
```

---

#### Update

Yeah this is something I need. So I can add further extensions in an array like you did `[ "lin1", "lin2" ... ]`.

The rest of my subroutine is:

```
sub find_newer_files {
    my ( $dirA, $extA, $dirB, $extB ) = @_;

    # read files and their mtime from dirA into a hash (fname => mtime)
    chdir $dirA or die "chdir($dirA) failed: $!";
    my %files_in_A = map { $_ => ( stat $_ )[9] } glob( "*.$extA" );

    # read files and their mtime from dirB into a hash (fname => mtime)
    chdir $dirB or die "chdir($dirB) failed: $!";
    my %files_in_B = map { $_ => ( stat $_ )[9] } glob( "*.$extB" );

    # for each found file in dirA
    for my $fileA ( keys %files_in_A ) {

        # replace extension for wanted file in dirB
        ( my $fileB = $fileA ) =~ s{\.\Q$extA\E$}{.$extB};

        warn "$fileA -> $fileB\n" if $ENV{DEBUG};

        # if we found a fileB in dirB
        if ( exists $files_in_B{$fileB} ) {

            # compare the timestamp; tell us when fileB is older than fileA
            if ( $files_in_A{$fileA} > $files_in_B{$fileB} ) {
                say "$fileB is older than $fileA";    #say
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Could you please elaborate what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: within the sub modul "find_newer_files" I compare files with the extension"lin" in directory A and "LINT" in directory B against each other. Now I will compare not only "lin"(A) and "LINT" (B). I will add more extensions

Comment: still not clear. `I will add more extentions` what do you mean? do you want to compare other extentions as well?

Comment: yes I will compare other extensions as well. At the moment I compare the Files *.lin and *.LINT each other. In addition to that I will compare *.adl and *.ADLT ...

Comment: ok, so what is the problem you experience?

Comment: I thought maybe there is a possibility to add these extensions inside my call `find_newer_files(
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin","...",  # directory_A => extension_A
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT","...", # directory B
    );` But I think I have to use a loop where I have to call for each extension the sub modul **sub find_newer_files** right?

Comment: Please show the rest of the subroutine that you have written. It will probably help us to understand what you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you mean something like:

```
...    
sub find_newer_files {
        my ( $dirA, $extA, $dirB, $extB ) = @_;
        my @found;
        if (ref $extA) {
            foreach my $i(0 .. $#{$extA}) {
                push @found, 
                    find_newer_files($dirA, $extA->[$i], $dirB, $extB->[$i]);
            }
            return @found;
        }
    .....
    find_newer_files(
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin",  # directory_A => extension_A
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT", # directory B
    );
    find_newer_files(
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => ["lin1","lin2","lin3"],  # directory_A => extension_A
        'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => ["LINT1","LINT2","LINT3"], # directory B
    );
...
```

By Adding this block

```
        my @found;
        if (ref $extA) {
            foreach my $i(0 .. $#{$extA}) {
                push @found, 
                    find_newer_files($dirA, $extA->[$i], $dirB, $extB->[$i]);
            }
            return @found;
        }
```

to the top of your function you could examine additional extensions (assuming you return nothing or a list of files).

so instead of writing:

```
find_newer_files(
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin1",  # directory_A => extension_A
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT1", # directory B
);
find_newer_files(
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin2",  # directory_A => extension_A
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT2", # directory B
);
find_newer_files(
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => "lin3",  # directory_A => extension_A
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => "LINT3", # directory B
);
```

you could use

```
find_newer_files(
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/AGF/lux/2016_12' => ["lin1","lin2","lin3"],  # directory_A => extension_A
    'D:/projects/Check_Tool/TAGF/lux' => ["LINT1","LINT2","LINT3"], # directory B
);
```

Comment: ***"+- typos"*** Please don't post untested code. At the very least you should make sure that it compiles.

Comment: Removed the typos.

Comment: No, you haven't. That code has never seen a compiler. This is a dreadful answer which guesses what the OP might mean without explaining that guess, and without describing how the "solution" works and what it assumes. It also doesn't stand a chance of working as it is.

Comment: @Borodin: Well i did check it here - but made a mistake (actually 2) when editing my answer, sorry.